# Why do my iptables logs have multiple LEN entries?

Tags: iptables, logs

I have some `iptables` logs in the following format:

```
Apr 11 01:11:26 ip-172-26-2-101 kernel: [297330.912420] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=02:ec:af:b6:94:ab:02:9e:70:8b:fd:38:08:00 SRC=169.254.169.254 DST=172.26.2.101 LEN=1897 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=6058 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=38118 WINDOW=488 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 11 01:11:26 ip-172-26-2-101 kernel: [297330.912443] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=02:ec:af:b6:94:ab:02:9e:70:8b:fd:38:08:00 SRC=169.254.169.254 DST=172.26.2.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=6059 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=38118 WINDOW=488 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Apr 11 01:11:26 ip-172-26-2-101 kernel: [297330.913183] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=02:ec:af:b6:94:ab:02:9e:70:8b:fd:38:08:00 SRC=169.254.169.254 DST=172.26.2.101 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=6060 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=38118 WINDOW=488 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 11 01:11:26 ip-172-26-2-101 kernel: [297330.913354] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.53 LEN=73 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35238 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35960 DPT=53 LEN=53 
Apr 11 01:11:26 ip-172-26-2-101 kernel: [297330.913789] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.53 LEN=73 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43410 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58295 DPT=53 LEN=53 
Apr 11 01:12:44 ip-172-26-2-101 kernel: [297409.163874] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=02:ec:af:b6:94:ab:02:9e:70:8b:fd:38:08:00 SRC=169.254.169.123 DST=172.26.2.101 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=60695 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=48765 LEN=56 
Apr 11 01:13:00 ip-172-26-2-101 kernel: [297425.271004] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=02:ec:af:b6:94:ab:02:9e:70:8b:fd:38:08:00 SRC=169.254.169.123 DST=172.26.2.101 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=60931 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=50534 LEN=56
```

As you can see, some of the lines have multiple `LEN` entries. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [forum post](https://forums.cabling-design.com/firewalls/iptable-log-analysis-len-property-appears-twice-23987-.htm), multiple `LEN` entries in `iptables` logs means that the first entry is the size of the whole IP packet, and any further entries are a breakdown of the size of the packets for individual protocols like UDP.

So if you're trying to do anything related to calculating the total data throughput for a time period or similar, use the first value in each line!